# Agregar un check a una serie de checkbox por medio de atributo value en jquery

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox

agradezco la ayuda sobre el problema que tengo.
Tengo una serie de checkbox cada uno con un value diferente, en medio de una operación, necesito seleccionar solo ciertos checkbox y por medio de jquery agregarles el check.

Este es el código que tengo para un select el cual funciona con jquery, necesito algo parecido pero para los checkboxs, puede ser que la solución sea sencilla, pero no he podido dar con la respuesta.

```js
$(".opciones > option[value='ejemplo']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="opciones" name="opciones"  id="opciones">
<option value="">Seleccione</option>
<option value="ejemplo">Ejemplo</option>
<option value="otraopcion">otra opcion</option>
</select>
```

Intente usar este codigo: $("#checkbox [value=ejemplo]").attr("checked", true); pero no me funciona, estoy usando la librería bootstrap 4, no se si eso tenga algo que ver.

Agradezco la ayuda posible.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Se le ocurre que puedes hacer algo asi, haciendo uso de la funcion `click()` de JQuery.

```js
$("#checks > input[type='checkbox' ][value='1']").attr("checked","checked")
$("#checks > input[type='checkbox' ][value='4']").attr("checked","checked")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="checks">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">Checkbox<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">Checkbox<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">Checkbox<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="4">Checkbox
</div>
```

Comment: No, no necesito obtener el valor del checkbox, si no que por medio de valor agregarle el checked de forma automática, como en el ejemplo del select que coloque en la pregunta. Muchas gracias

Comment: Listo, puedes checarlo, setee de forma automatica el valor del primer checbox y puedes hacerlo con todos los que quieras

Comment: Woow, con que así era, perfecto, mil gracias.